# JOLT - Remove duplicates in array

Tags: json, jolt

I need to remove duplicates from **docAddrs** array from my document and keep the rest of the json unchanged. The last transformation is moving all the data into **docAddrs** array, instead of just the addr objects. This is what I tried:

**Input:**

```json
{
  "docId1": "1",
  "docId2": "2",
  "docInfo": {
    "info1": "info1",
    "info2": "info2",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineNum": "1",
        "val": "1"
      },
      {
        "lineNum": "2",
        "val": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "docAddrs": [
    {
      "addrId": "111",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "st": "st"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "111",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "st": "st"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "112",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "st": "st2"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "112",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "st": "st2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": "@addrId[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "docId1": "docId1",
        "docId2": "docId2",
        "docInfo": "docInfo",
        "@": "docAddrs.[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "docId1": "1",
  "docId2": "2",
  "docInfo": {
    "info1": "info1",
    "info2": "info2",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineNum": "1",
        "val": "1"
      },
      {
        "lineNum": "2",
        "val": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "111": [
    {
      "addrId": "111",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "st": "st"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "111",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "st": "st"
    }
  ],
  "112": [
    {
      "addrId": "112",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "st": "st2"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "112",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "st": "st2"
    }
  ]  
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
{
  "docId1": "1",
  "docId2": "2",
  "docInfo": {
    "info1": "info1",
    "info2": "info2",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineNum": "1",
        "val": "1"
      },
      {
        "lineNum": "2",
        "val": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "docAddrs": [
    {
      "addrId": "111",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "st": "st"
    },
    {
      "addrId": "112",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "st": "st2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please suggest how I can get this to work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of the following specs

```json
[
  //exchange key-value pairs for "docAddrs" array
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3[@(2,addrId)].@(0)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // pick only the first components of the values from the newly formed array type values
  // those already have identical components per each 
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // exchange key-value pairs again in order to collect each value array pairs 
  // under common keys respectively
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.@(0)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // dissipate each value components to their related object
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The Demo on http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/
[image]

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Barbaros, I just realized this will not work if any of the values is repeated in the docAddrs objects, eg,., if value of "city" is same across all "docAddrs" objects("city": "Boston"), this spec will not work as expected. I'm looking for a solution where the docAddrs.addrId is used as the key to remove duplicate docAddr objects

Comment: Hi @Gopi , that's a good catch! I've just fixed by replacing `[0]` with `[@(2,addrId)]` for `"$": "&3[0].@(0)"` so as to consider that as a primary key id.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, sorry for the late response, this transform fails when addrId is more than 7 chars long. ex., if you have addrId: 12345678, the transform does not return a result. I ran it in Java client and the object returned by Chainr.transform() returns: "{docId=9693348241, docAddrs=[null, null,...]}" The null repeats more than a thousand times.  JsonUtils.toJsonString(transformedOutput) never returns, looks like it's going in an infinite loop

Comment: Hi @Gopi no problem. Yes, it seems interesting that I just tested on the demo site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ for "addrId": "1234567" with no occurence of any problem, but for "addrId": "12345678" it does! I don't know whether it's a known bug, then perhaps the community(https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) might help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "docAddrs": {
        "*": "addr.@addrId[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "addr": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "addr": {
        "*": {
          "@": "docAddrs.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```